# Creating a Measure to Calculate a Column Value Based on the Previous Row in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm facing a significant challenge, and I can't seem to move forward; there might not even be a solution. I'm building a dashboard to visualize some inflation rates. I've created a table with monthly indices of a certain index, and I need to calculate the cumulative value depending on the period the user filters. Here's where the problems begin.

I've set up a table and created a dynamic sorter in the visualization using a measure:
Order =
RANKX(
ALLSELECTED(Indices [Monthreference]),
[Order aux],,ASC)

So when the user, for example, filters the last 12 months, they'll see a table with 12 rows, numbered from the oldest month-year as 1 and so on.

Now I need to calculate the cumulative value, which isn't as simple as just summing or averaging. There's a rule, and for that, I have to calculate another factor called "Centesimal."

If there's only one month or the first month (row 1), the centesimal is "Index/100 + 1."
2nd month/row: Index/100 + 1 * Previous Centesimal

I can't reference the same column to calculate the new centesimal based on the previous centesimal. Is there a way to do this?

I can't add a new column because this calculation needs to remain dynamic. If the base has 100 rows, numbered from 1 to 100, when the user filters to 12 rows, the calculation won't be correct because the index of the first month will change.

Any idea how can I do that?

Here's a sample:

Hi. Here is a sample:

| Order | Month | IGPM | Centesimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11 | -0.95 | 0,9905000 * |
| 2 | 2022-12 | -0.97 | 0,9808922 ** |
| 3 | 2023-01 | -0.56 | 0,9753992 |
| 4 | 2023-02 | 0.45 | 0,9797885 |
| 5 | 2023-03 | 0.21 | 0,9818460 |
| 6 | 2023-04 | -0.06 | 0,9812569 |
| 7 | 2023-05 | 0.05 | 0,9817475 |
| 8 | 2023-06 | -0.95 | 0,9724209 |
| 9 | 2023-07 | -1.84 | 0,9545284 |
| 10 | 2023-08 | -1.93 | 0,9361060 |
| 11 | 2023-09 | -0.72 | 0,9293660 |
| 12 | 2023-10 | -0.14 | 0,9280649 |

- "First Centesimal = IGPM /100 + 1"
  ** "Next Centesimal = (IGPM / 100 + 1) x Last Centesimal"
  *** "Result = (IGPM #12 / 100 + 1) x Centesimal # 11"

Final Result:
Last Centesimal: 0,9280649
I need only the last... it can be show at a card.

Comment: Can you add simplified sample data and desired results?

Comment: Hi. I inserted a sample at my question! Thanks

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Pay attention that is -0.0095 (NEGATIVE) plus 1 (POSITIVE). So the result is 0,9905